Is there a spell to teleport all your allies to you?
I'm quite sure I've seen something along those lines but not sure if it was 3.5 or Pathfinder 1.0.
Use case: get everyone in combat (other PC's, pets, summons) close to use Mass Heal or some buff that requires group hug to work.

Are you only wanting PF-1e answers as per the tag or are you looking for D&D-3.5 as well?

Pure PF 1.0. In 3.5 there's plenty of answers but PF 1.0, while still maintaining the overall 3.5 feel also removed a lot of FOTM-level stuff, especially when it comes to repositioning everyone in combat and cheating action economy.

Signifier's Rally does this, but it's [evil].
Link: https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/signifier-s-rally/
There's also a Rogue talent that does the same thing, for some reason.

It's sad that such baseline effect is so limited and so high level... but apparently, that's what we get :(
